# Using Vieta's Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Given that $p$ is a prime, let all solutions to $$x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dots+x+1=0$$ be $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_{p-1}$.
>
> Find the value of $$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (1-x_i)^{1-p}$$

A friend gave me this, and it proved to be more difficult than initially imagined.

Vieta's formula seemed ineffective in solving the problem. So I attempted to use that $$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \ln (x-x_i) =\ln (x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dots+x+1)$$

And then try to derive both sides. This proved ineffective.

So how would one evalue the above sum?

Comment: 1. using binomial theorem, express that expression as a double summation. 2. exchange the double summation. 3. Now you have a sum of powers of roots of unity. How does this simplify the double summation?

Comment: @user2770287: The sum you get from the binomial theorem is divergent, so you have to work a little harder than this...

Comment: @Micah: Oh that's $1-p$. I read that as $p-1$. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we consider the meromorphic function
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)z^{p-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(1-z)^p} \tag{1}$$
It has a multiple pole at $z=0$ and simple poles at $1,z_1,\ldots z_{p-1}$, where $z_j=1-x_j$.
 The sum of its residues is zero, and

$$ \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=z_k\right) = \lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z-z_k}{(1-z)z^{p-1}\left(1-(1-z)^p\right)}=\frac{1}{(1-z_k)z_k^{p-1}}\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{1}{p(1-z)^{p-1}} $$
holds by De l'Hopital rule. It follows that:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{z_k^{p-1}}=-p\cdot\left[\text{Res}(f(z),z=0)+\text{Res}(f(z),z=1)\right]\tag{2} $$
and the problem boils down to the computation of two residues.

Comment: What exactly is the kind of residue you are discussing? Could you link me to an article explaining it? (and what are poles?) I haven't studied extensively beyond high school mathematics.

Comment: @S.C.B.:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem